# How do I use session variables with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, local-storage

I have a button on one page another button on a different page. This second button has the text in it "0 items selected". When the first button is clicked I want to increase the number in the second button by one.

Seeing it is transferring data over different pages I didn't manage to do it the standard way.

Please do not suggest PHP, I am unable to use it.

```js
var yetVisited = localStorage[0];

if ($('.#CallToActionCustomise').click()){
 localStorage++;
}
$('.#CallToActionCustomise').click(function(){
 $(".Main_MenuButtonReview").append(localStorage);
});
```

```html
<button class="Main_MenuButtonReview">0 items selected <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
```

Comment: localStorage is not an array. it's an object. you cannot increment an object? define a variable inside the localStorage and it will work: `localStorage.myCounter` for example

Answer (score 1):

You need to access localStorage as if it were an Object, not an array.

Also, you can only store String values, so to get a number to perform math on, you will need to use `parseInt`.

```
localStorage.setItem('yetVisited', 0);

$(".Main_MenuButtonReview").text(localStorage.yetVisited + ' items selected');

$('.CallToActionCustomise').click(function()){
    localStorage.yetVisited = parseInt(localStorage.yetVisited) + 1;
    $(".Main_MenuButtonReview").text(localStorage.yetVisited + ' items selected');
}
```

Here's an [example](https://codepen.io/BrandonKerr/pen/EwZbMK).

Comment: Doesn't seem to show the number, do i need to add anything to the html for this work?

Comment: You have your event listener inside an if statement. That prevents it from ever getting added. I didn't catch it, but I'll update the answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work sorry. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Difference is that mine is increasing one buttons number with another

Comment: Your jQuery selector is invalid too. Use '.' for class selector, and '#' for id selector. You can't use both, though.

Comment: You'll need to set the text on the second page, as well. Without waiting for the click event.

Comment: I spotted that too. I have changed it to the right selector but still no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155285/discussion-between-bricky-and-dale).

Comment: Hey could you please explain to me in the chat where it waits for the page load

Comment: When i clear the localstorage it comes up with undefined when i try to run the code. I've tried researching this but no luck. It's only when i clear the local storage though. I clear the local storage cause i want the number to go back to 0 on page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, I think you need to init some tag when it loaded.

Put this code on another page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof localStorage.yetVisited === 'undefined') {
        localStorage.setItem('yetVisited', 0);
    }
    yetVisited = localStorage.yetVisited;
    $('.Main_MenuButtonReview').text(yetVisited + ' items selected');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 // this area means after your page(document) ready completely.
});
```